# Difference in terminal and PHP curl versions

Tags: php, curl, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to make a file upload with additional parameters in terminal, I use the `-F` param to combine all the parameters I need, here is what I got:

`curl -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -F "video=@174deab3-a7c6-4410-a304-d7ee49b28900.mp4" -F "videoExt=mp4" -F "videoSize=10230" -F "thumbExt=png" -F "thumb=IufIsduSii823" -F "id=8" http://test.dev/test.php`

The problem is that on the handling side (test.php) the **$_FILES** array is empty.

Then I tried to make a simple html form that will post to the handler a file, and I tried to make the curl request with `php_curl`. Here goes the code:

```
    $postargs = [
        'videoExt' => 'mp4',
        'id' => 8,
        'thumb' => 'IkJdfjiaskdkI*82',
        'thumbExt' => 'png',
        'videoSize' => '10240'
    ];
foreach ($_FILES as $param => $file) {
        $postargs[$param] = '@' . $file['tmp_name'] . ';filename=' . $file['name'] . ';type=' . $file['type'];
    }

    $header = array("Content-type: multipart/form-data");
    $ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postargs);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

This script succesfully makes a curl request to the handler and the file is uploaded. Please advise what is the difference, and how can I achieve that in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me, try use `-i` option, eg.:

```
curl -i -F "video=@174deab3-a7c6-4410-a304-d7ee49b28900.mp4" -F "videoExt=mp4" -F "videoSize=10230" -F "thumbExt=png" -F "thumb=IufIsduSii823" -F "id=8" http://localhost:8080
```

> -i, --include Include protocol headers in the output (H/F)

Comment: tried that, but it changes nothing, the `-i` option just gives me the response headers

Comment: @VitKos what version? Tried `curl --version` for get version.

Comment: curl 7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3

Comment: is very old, use debian usually have older software that ubuntu, the version on my debian is 7.26. Tried `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`?